# is it understandable to use 'adequate vehicle' in the following context

Tags: vocabulary, american-english, learning

I have an adequate vehicle for your needs' to mean a vehicle one can rent that satisfy their needs?

regarding the use of the adjective in that order: 'adequate vehicle', is that correct for this context?

Comment: Which is your question: "**available** vehicle" or "**adequate** vehicle"?

Comment: I've written an answer, but can you explain why you have a doubt about the word adequate here.

Comment: @JamesK sure, my doubt is regarding adjective use order, whether it shold be: 'I have an adequate vehicle for your needs' OR 'I have an  vehicle adequate for your needs'

Comment: In my opinion _a vehicle [which is] adequate for your needs_ would be better, but your version would be acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

"Adequate" has its usual dictionary meaning here.  It tends to suggest that it *only* satisfies their needs. It doesn't satisfy their desires. The vehicle is okay, it's not good.

The attributive adjective goes in front of the noun like this in nearly all cases in English.

Comment: so is it wrong to use the adjective before the noun?

Comment: The attributive adjective goes in front of the noun

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might want to say "a suitable vehicle" if it fits all their needs